# Loading html head tag common files in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp

I am new to Java and I have set up a Maven/Spring 4 environment in NetBeans 8.

In PHP and ColdFusion I would create one file that loads the css and javascript files and include that file in all views in order to make one point of change.

I would like to do that in Java but I am not sure what the best practice would be.  I have the files in the resources directory under WEB-INF and in the css and js folders respectively.

Should I create a jsp file that has the link and script paths and include the jsp file in others, use an xml file, combination of both or something else?

Comment: you can use `<jsp:include  page="common.jsp"/>`

Comment: That is what I was going to do but I wanted to make sure that would be an acceptable and efficient java practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

**Static includes**

Static includes are the equivalent to copy-pasting code into the page you're calling it from. This means that a static include will be executed in the current page context.

```
<%@include file="page.html"%>
```

**Dynamic includes**

Dynamic includes are requests evaluated in their own context, and then output to the page you're calling it from

```
<jsp:include page="page.html" />
```

Since the dynamic include is a request, you can send parameters like this

```
<jsp:include page="page.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="myVar" value="${someValue}"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I wanted to verify that as a acceptable java practice.

Answer (score 0):

For Easy to learn and run Templating the component in `Jsp`, like `header` `body` and `footer` when you are developing page only `body` of page change then use [apache tile](https://tiles.apache.org/). It is xml configuration template composition framework.

Here is snippet of tile.xml

```
<definition name="base.definitions" template="/WEB-INF/page/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/page/include/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/page/include/menu.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/page/include/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="login" template="/WEB-INF/page/loginlayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/page/include/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

> Should I create a jsp file that has the link and script paths and include the jsp file in others

for this you create `header.jsp` and include all the `js` and `css`

Apache Tiles will render it all for you.

if you dont have that many of `jsp` pages  then use `<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />` in your content page.